# Thunar: No zooming possible anymore with ctrl and mouse wheel

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

I have used Xubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver, and one of the very useful features was the simple zooming of file icons with ctrl and the mouse wheel. Because the file icons are... image previews.

Now, in 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish, it does not work anymore.

Does anybody have a workaround?

Comment: Is it a new "feature", mentioned in changelog, or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can still zoom in and out in Thunar 1.8.1 which is the version present in Xubuntu 18.10 but to do so, you'll need the keyboard:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> pressed repeatedly will zoom in

[image: Zoom in]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will zoom out

[image: Zoom out]

I couldn't find specific information about the mouse route in the [release notes](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/18.10/release-notes) or in the [link to Thunar 1.8.1](https://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce-announce/2018-June/000614.html) in the release notes.

Comment: Yes, I know that. It's a hassle... when I navigate with Thunar, I want to have one hand on the keyboard, and the other on the mouse.